# Error: Cannot find module 'underscore' thrown in console for all Meteor commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, underscore.js, meteorite

**Error: Cannot find module 'underscore' thrown in console for all Meteor commands**

After every meteor or meteorite command such as `meteor` or `mrt create myapp` the following error is thrown. This error seemed to appear suddenly, as meteor was functional the night before and no changes have been made since.

```
Austins-MacBook-Pro:Projects austinrivas$ mrt create test-app

/Users/austinrivas/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/meteor.js:1480
}).run();
   ^
Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at /Users/austinrivas/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/tools/meteor.js:10:11
```

I have tried installing underscore manually with `sudo npm install -g underscore` which returns

```
Austins-MacBook-Pro:Projects austinrivas$ sudo npm install -g underscore
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.5.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.5.2.tgz
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova requires colors@'>=0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/node-static requires colors@'>=0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
underscore@1.5.2 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/underscore
```

My ~/.bash_profile has the following paths

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules"
export NODE_OPTIONS="--debug"
```

I've even tried reinstalling node and doing an `npm cache clean` but I'm not sure what else to try.

Any further insight would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Running `npm list -g underscore` returns the following

```
Austins-MacBook-Pro:~ austinrivas$ npm list -g underscore
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova requires colors@'>=0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/node-static requires colors@'>=0.6.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
/usr/local/share/npm/lib
├─┬ meteorite@0.6.11
│ ├─┬ ddp@0.3.4
│ │ └─┬ meteor-ejson@0.6.3
│ │   └── underscore@1.4.4
│ └── underscore@1.5.1
├─┬ phonegap@3.0.0-0.14.0
│ └─┬ cordova@3.0.0
│   ├─┬ follow-redirects@0.0.3
│   │ └── underscore@1.5.1
│   └─┬ plugman@0.9.10
│     ├─┬ dep-graph@1.1.0
│     │ └── underscore@1.2.1
│     └── underscore@1.4.4
├── underscore@1.5.2
└─┬ ungit@0.1.8
  └── underscore@1.4.4
```

Comment: Do you get this:  mrt --version

    Meteorite version 0.6.11

    Release 0.6.5.1

Comment: when I `mrt --version` I get `Meteorite version 0.6.11` then it hangs for a momment and I get the same error

Comment: Then it is meteor itself which should be reinstalled.  Does "node --version" work?  Something like 10.17...

Comment: @JimMack yes `node --version` works fine, it return `v0.10.18`. I'm going to try reinstalling `meteor` again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve this error by completely uninstalling / reinstalling `meteor` and `meteorite` through the following steps.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
rm -rf ~/.meteor
sudo mrt uninstall
sudo mrt uninstall --system
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

I was able to verifying everything was working properly by running `meteor --version` and `mrt create test-app`

Answer (score 0):

First off, your meteorite is out of date. To update meteorite run (sudo if applicable):

```
npm update -g meteorite
```

If you ran the 'mrt' or 'meteor' command as sudo in the past, [it will cause issues](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite#permission-woes). Clear meteorite by running:

```
sudo mrt uninstall
sudo mrt uninstall --system
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

You also want to remove the 'build' folder inside existing projects, located in '/project/.meteor/local/build'

Comment: Thanks @FredericoC, I followed your instructions and reinstalled meteorite with `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite` because I was receiving a permissions error otherwise.

Unfortunately I am still receiving the same `underscore` error whenever I try to run an `mrt` or `meteor` command.