# Error: Cannot find module 'underscore' thrown from boot.js in meteor bundle

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I'm using meteor and meteorite's npm module. Not sure the issue is even related to that but ... I have a small project I'm trying to deploy to a vagrant virtualbox but when I start it I get

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/projects/myapp/live/programs/server/boot.js:5:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678924/error-cannot-find-module-underscore-thrown-in-console-for-all-meteor-commands) but it doesn't *seem* to be related. Everything works fine for me in development (meaning from the source folder vs the deployed version).

mrt --version reports

```
$ mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.7.4
Release 0.8.3
```

my `packages.json` for mrt npm is

```
{
  "winston": "0.7.3",
  "winston-loggly": "1.0.1"
}
```

Not too big. My `smart.json` for mrt is

```
{
  "packages": {
    "collection-api": {},
    "iron-router": {},
    "npm": {}
  }
}
```

I'm not using `require` anywhere, only `Meteor.require`

I even tried

```
mkdir delme
cd delme
mrt create test.app
meteor bundle --directory ../live
```

It creates the same `programs/server/boot.js` including underscore which doesn't exist. I followed the instructions in the readme. I have `fiber` and `bcrypt` installed in the virtualbox like it mentions in the readme.

I tried installing `underscore` manually. I then started getting an error about the `source-map-support` module. So I added that. I then started getting an error about missing the `semver` module, so I added that and yet another module was missing. Clearly I've missed a step or something but I'm not having any luck finding it.

ideas?

---

### Update #1

so I installed meteor from scratch on the virtualbox

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
meteor create test.app
meteor bundle --directory ../test
cd ../test
rm -r programs/server/node_modules/fibers
rm -r programs/server/node_modules/bcrypt
npm install fibers@1.0.1
npm install bcrypt@0.7.7    
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://user:password@host:port/databasename'
export ROOT_URL='http://example.com'
node main.js
```

That worked.

Checking the `programs/server/node_modules` directory in that one

```
ls test/programs/server/node_modules/
eachline  fstream   http-proxy  keypress      npm      semver      source-map-support  underscore
esprima   heapdump  kexec       node-aes-gcm  request  source-map  tar
```

Where as the one showing the issues is

```
ls /var/projects/myapp/live/programs/server/node_modules 
bcrypt  fibers
```

maybe something has broken my original `meteor bundle`?

---

### Update #2

**SO EMBARRASSING!**  The issue is I have `node_modules` in my `.gitignore` and I'm transferring the files through git. :P

Comment: So you're seeing this problem only on the server you're deploying to and not your dev box?

Comment: are you using underscore in any "special" way? i.e., do you have packages you wrote yourself using it, or are you `require`-ing it somehow? (`Npm.require`)

Comment: Yes i'm seeing this on the server I'm deploying too. I'm not using underscore at all. Meteor is using underscore. See above I get the same error on `test.app` which is generated by Meteor.

Comment: should I leave this Q up or delete it?